# converting SSE code to AVX - cost of _mm256_and_ps

Tags: c, sse, avx

I'm converting SSE2 sine and cosine functions (from Julien Pommier's sse_mathfun.h; based on the CEPHES sinf function) to use AVX in order to accept 8 float vectors or 4 doubles.

So, Julien's function sin_ps becomes sin_ps8 (for 8 floats) and sin_pd4 for 4 doubles. (The "advanced" editor here fails to accept my code, so please visit http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1227375 to see it.)

Testing with clang 3.3 under Mac OS X 10.6.8 running on a 2011 Core2 i7 @ 2.7Ghz, benchmarking results look like this:

- sinf .. ->   27.7 millions of vector evaluations/second over 5.56e+07
  iters (standard, scalar sinf() function)

  sin_ps .. ->   41.0 millions of vector evaluations/second over
  8.22e+07 iters

  sin_pd4 .. ->   40.2 millions of vector evaluations/second over
  8.06e+07 iters

  sin_ps8 .. ->    2.5 millions of vector evaluations/second over
  5.1e+06 iters

The cost of sin_ps8 is downright frightening, and it seems it is due to the use of _mm256_castsi256_ps . In fact, commenting out the line "poly_mask = _mm256_castsi256_ps(emmm2);" results in a more normal performance.
sin_pd4 uses _mm_castsi128_pd, but it appears that is not (just) the mix of SSE and AVX instructions that is biting me in sin_ps8: when I emulate the _mm256_castsi256_ps calls with 2 calls to _mm_castsi128_ps, performance doesn't improve. emm2 and emm0 are pointers to emmm2 and emmm0, both v8si instances and thus (a priori) correctly aligned to 32 bits boundaries.

See [sse_mathfun.h](https://github.com/RJVB/MacSTL/blob/master/test/sse_mathfun.h) and [sse_mathfun_test.c](https://github.com/RJVB/MacSTL/blob/master/test/sse_mathfun_test.c) for compilable code.

Is there a(n easy) way to avoid the penalty I'm seeing?

Comment: Really sorry about the missing code: the preview looked fine but my text was refused for posting...

Comment: Agner Fog's [optimization tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals) show that `ANDPS` and `VANDPS` have a latency of 1 cycle on Ivy Bridge and Haswell, no matter the argument size. Additionally, `_mm256_castsi256_ps` does not actually emit any instructions -- it's a true type cast, purely in the compiler. Your problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: There's several points I'd like to bring up. First, we would love it if you could post the assembler code for all the functions, both Julien's and yours. On Mac OS X 10.6.8 you may do this with `otool -tV -p <name of function prefixed with underscore>`. Second, since you're using intrinsics, I expect the compiler will select VEX-prefixed instruction encodings that don't cause SSE-AVX transition penalties. I doubt your problem is due to SSE-AVX transitions.

Comment: Third, you're using some 256-bit integer math here. Based on the release date of your CPU, and the fact it has AVX, it's an Intel Sandy Bridge.

 Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge only support the AVX instruction set, unlike Haswell which also supports AVX2. The AVX instruction set only includes in full 256-bit width the _floating-point_ operations, while the integer instructions are still 128-bit wide. AVX2 is the instruction set that also has full-width integer operations.

Comment: I don't see him using 256-bit integer math anywhere

Comment: I see `_mm_cvttps_epi32`, `_mm_cvtepi32_ps`, `_mm_slli_epi32` `_mm_and_si128` and `_mm_cmpeq_epi32`, at a minimum.

Comment: Not sure if you're doing this for a learning exercise or not, but if you just want to find something that works, you can find an already-done AVX translation of the SSE2 functions you referenced [at this site](http://software-lisc.fbk.eu/avx_mathfun/).

Comment: `_mm_*` are 128-bit instructions. 256-bit ones all start with `_mm256_*`.

Answer (score 1):

Transferring stuff out of registers into memory isn't usually a good idea. You are doing this every time you store into a pointer.

Instead of this:

```
{ ALIGN32_BEG v4sf *yy ALIGN32_END = (v4sf*) &y;
         emm2[0] = _mm_and_si128(_mm_add_epi32( _mm_cvttps_epi32( yy[0] ), _v4si_pi32_1), _v4si_pi32_inv1),
         emm2[1] = _mm_and_si128(_mm_add_epi32( _mm_cvttps_epi32( yy[1] ), _v4si_pi32_1), _v4si_pi32_inv1);
         yy[0] = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(emm2[0]),
         yy[1] = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(emm2[1]);
      }

/* get the swap sign flag */
emm0[0] = _mm_slli_epi32(_mm_and_si128(emm2[0], _v4si_pi32_4), 29),
emm0[1] = _mm_slli_epi32(_mm_and_si128(emm2[1], _v4si_pi32_4), 29);

/* get the polynom selection mask
there is one polynom for 0 <= x <= Pi/4
and another one for Pi/4<x<=Pi/2

Both branches will be computed.
*/
emm2[0] = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(_mm_and_si128(emm2[0], _v4si_pi32_2), _mm_setzero_si128()),
emm2[1] = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(_mm_and_si128(emm2[1], _v4si_pi32_2), _mm_setzero_si128());

((v4sf*)&poly_mask)[0] = _mm_castsi128_ps(emm2[0]);
((v4sf*)&poly_mask)[1] = _mm_castsi128_ps(emm2[1]);
swap_sign_bit = _mm256_castsi256_ps(emmm0);
```

Try something like this:

```
__m128i emm2a = _mm_and_si128(_mm_add_epi32( _mm256_castps256_ps128(y), _v4si_pi32_1), _v4si_pi32_inv1);
__m128i emm2b = _mm_and_si128(_mm_add_epi32( _mm256_extractf128_ps(y, 1), _v4si_pi32_1), _v4si_pi32_inv1);

y = _mm256_insertf128_ps(_mm256_castps128_ps256(_mm_cvtepi32_ps(emm2a)), _mm_cvtepi32_ps(emm2b), 1);

/* get the swap sign flag */
__m128i emm0a = _mm_slli_epi32(_mm_and_si128(emm2a, _v4si_pi32_4), 29),
__m128i emm0b = _mm_slli_epi32(_mm_and_si128(emm2b, _v4si_pi32_4), 29);

swap_sign_bit = _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_insertf128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(emm0a), emm0b, 1));

/* get the polynom selection mask
there is one polynom for 0 <= x <= Pi/4
and another one for Pi/4<x<=Pi/2

Both branches will be computed.
*/
emm2a = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(_mm_and_si128(emm2a, _v4si_pi32_2), _mm_setzero_si128()),
emm2b = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(_mm_and_si128(emm2b, _v4si_pi32_2), _mm_setzero_si128());

poly_mask = _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_insertf128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(emm2a), emm2b, 1));
```

As mentioned in comments, `cast` intrinsics are purely compile-time and emit no instructions.

Comment: Re: cast intrinsics: indeed. I compared pure _mm*_cast*_ps intrinsics, and they're all *fast*.

So I have SSE2 integer code, and two AVX casts, and if I outcomment both casts (or indeed a specific one, IIRC to calculate poly_mask), performance soars all of a sudden. I must be a little careful interpreting that because of the way sse_mathfun_test stores the benched function result into its operand to avoid loop unrolling (performance can go a little too much over the top ;) ), but still this suggests that I'm taking a hit because of the conversion.

Comment: Alignment issue, load/store delay, I have too little knowledge of assembler coding, but I've seen enough feedback from Apple's Shark tool to suspect something like that is going on. (And no, Shark doesn't help me here, my version apparently doesn't know AVX yet.)

And indeed my CPU doesn't have AVX2 yet, sadly.

Comment: Does removing the memory usage like I've done here help?

Comment: Have you tested your code?

NB: to my shame, there must be a conversion error the code I posted, because the functions don't compute the correct sine and cosines. So much for relying on someone else's unit tests...

Comment: But to answer your question, yes. Or rather, when I take avx_ssemathfun.h and modify it to use my approach with 2 __m128 pointers to a __m256, the result is slower than with Garberoglio's cast via a temp. union. Turns out one can even use an inline function:

    inline void copy_xmm_to_imm( v4si xmm0_, v4si xmm1_, v8si *imm_ )
    {
        ALIGN32_BEG imm_xmm_union u ALIGN32_END;
        u.xmm[0]=xmm0_, u.xmm[1]=xmm1_;
        *imm_ = u.imm;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could compare your code to the already working AVX extension of Julien Pommier SSE math functions?

http://software-lisc.fbk.eu/avx_mathfun/

This code works in GCC but not MSVC and only supports floats (float8) but I think you could easily extend it to use doubles (double4) as well.  A quick comparison of your `sin` function shows that they are quite similar except for the SSE2 integer part.

Comment: I remember I had to do some work to get sse_mathfun.h to compile under MSVC, I could presumably do the same thing with the AVX version. I honestly didn't yet get around to looking if someone did the work, in part because indeed I'm doing this also as an exercise.
That said, is there really an advantage to doing the conversion his way, using a temporary union and "scalar pointers" instead of using a pointer to an __m256 instance that allows to access that variable as an __m128[2]? If the casting is really done only compile-time, without alignment adjusting, there ought to be no difference.

Comment: Also, I tried using a union containing an __m256 and an __m128[2] ... but gcc and clang both balk at that.

In any event, when I do that quick comparison, I have the distinct impression that the really different integer part is for AVX2 ... 

Guess the easiest thing to do would be to go time avx_sse_mathfun.h :)